# Integrate over right hand upper part of circle, r = 2*cos(θ)

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

This is what I am pretty sure is right, and understand. You integrate from $0$ to $\frac {π}{4} $ radians, but where does you $r$, radius begin when you integrate? It must be some kind of function, going from the cartesian coordinate points $(2,0)$ to $(1,0)$, and then up to $(1,2)$.

$$\int_0^{\fracπ4} \int_?^{2cos(θ)}\ r \,drdθ$$

[image]

Other solutions that may or may not be correct, need answers.

$\int_{0}^{2π} \int_0^{2cos(θ)}\ r \,drdθ$  - $\int_{\fracπ4}^{2π} \int_0^{2cos(θ)}\ r \,drdθ$

Comment: $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}], r \in [0,1]$

Comment: First quadrant is everything above the $x$ axis and to the right of the $y$ axis....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret you correctly, you want to integrate over the red quarter circle, in terms of ordinary polar coordinates centered at the origin $(0,0)$. Then the lower limit for $r$ is given by starting at the line $x=r\cos \theta=1$, i.e., $r=1/\cos \theta$.